# WSO2 6.5.0 Management Console Login Issues

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I have installed wso2 6.5.0 I am unable to login into management console. I want to enable the connectors through the management console. After installing the product i can able to login only one time after that it showing an error like "Login Failed! Please recheck username and Password and Try again" Please someone could help me to sort out the issues.

Comment: Can you please post the stack trace of the error (wso2carbon.log) at the time of logging?

Comment: Hi.. First of all no error at the time of logging.In management console it simply shows                                                                                                           Login failed! Please recheck the username and password and try again.
In wso2carbon.log it simply shows                                
CarbonAuthenticationUtil 'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2019-07-30 11:20:38,462+0530] Suppose if i do installation and then again installation also it will login only one time,after that same thing only happening. Please guide me to sort out the issue

Comment: Have you changed any configurations? I am not facing any issues with my installations.

Comment: Nope. I didn't do any changes with configuration and all.

Comment: I did Uninstall and then again installed, same thing only showing. Same issue i was faced with 6.4.0 and now again same issues with 6.5.0 also. Suppose error or exception coming means can check but i doesn't throw any error or exception at all.

Comment: Hi Sumathi, are you using the embedded H2 database?

Comment: Hi Dileesha, No am not using embedded database

Comment: Hi Sumathi, In that case, can you add the master-datasources.xml and user-mgt.xml file content to the question? Looks like the problem might be with the data source as you are not using H2 DB.